# Numpy ndarray data ownership problem on reshape and view

Tags: python, numpy, ownership, shallow-copy

I am confused about the ownership mechanism in numpy.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(10)
a.flags.owndata     # True
id(a)               # 140289740187168
```

The first four lines is obvious, variable `a` owns data of id `140289740187168`.

```
b = a
c = a.view()
d = a.reshape((2, 5))
print(b.flags.owndata, b.base, id(b.base)) # True None 94817978163056
print(c.flags.owndata, c.base, id(c.base)) # False [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] 140289740187168
print(d.flags.owndata, d.base, id(d.base)) # False [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] 140289740187168
id(None)                                   # 94817978163056
```

Variable `c,d` are all "shallow" copy from `a`, so none of both own data. `b` is `a` and owns data (shared with `a`).

```
a = a.view()
print(id(a))                               # 140289747003632
print(a.flags.owndata, a.base, id(a.base)) # False [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] 140289740187168
```

However, assigning view of `a` to `a` creates a new variable of id `140289747003632` and leaves the data ownership to the previous old `a` of id `140289740187168`.

The question is, since old `a` has been overloaded by the new `a`, it would be more reasonable to transfer the data ownership to the new `a`. Why the old `a` still keeps the data ownership?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
b = a
```

`b` is `a`, just a different name for the same object.  That's not even a copy.

These are `views`.  A view is a new array, but it uses the same data buffer (as shown by the `base`:

```
c = a.view()
d = a.reshape((2, 5))
```

I like to use `__array_interface__` to look at the basic attributes of an array:

```
In [210]: a = np.arange(10)
In [211]: a.__array_interface__
Out[211]: 
{'data': (43515408, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (10,),
 'version': 3}
```

The `data[0]` is some sort of representation of where the values or data of `a` are stored.

A `view` will have the same 'data' (with a possible offset).  Otherwise the `view` has its own `strides` and `shape`.  It is a new array object with shared `base`:

```
In [212]: d = a.reshape((2,5))
In [213]: d.__array_interface__
Out[213]: 
{'data': (43515408, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (2, 5),
 'version': 3}
```

Assigning the `view` to `a` does not change the original array or data buffer.  The original `a` array object still exists in memory, along with its data buffer.

```
In [214]: a = a.view()
In [216]: a.__array_interface__['data']
Out[216]: (43515408, False)
```

If `numpy` 'updated' the `a.base` as you suggest, it would have to also update it for all views of the original `a` such as `d`.

```
In [218]: id(a)
Out[218]: 139767778126704
In [219]: id(a.base)
Out[219]: 139768132465328
In [220]: id(d.base)
Out[220]: 139768132465328
```

While python and `numpy` maintain some sort of reference count to determine what objects are garbage, `numpy` does not maintain a record of what `views` have been made.  That is, while `d.base` links `d` to `a`, there's isn't a link the other way.